# Show $0 < v < 1$ under the following conditions

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

If,

$$ x = u \cdot v $$

$$ y = u \cdot (1 - v) $$

$$ 0 < x < \infty $$

$$ 0 < y < \infty $$

Show that:

$$ 0 < v < 1 $$

Any idea to show that inequality?

Comment: What are $u$ and $v$, calculated out of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: *Hint:* $v$ and $1-v$ must have the same sign.

Comment: Ideally you should show an attempt at an answer and add some context as to why the question arrises.

Comment: v>0 and 1-v>0 then 1>v . Hence, 0<v<1 is that true sir?

Answer (score 2):

From

$$x = uv>0$$

We get

$$u \neq 0, v \neq 0$$

So we have

$$u = \frac{x}{v}$$

Then since we have

$$y = u(1-v)$$

We get

$$y = \frac{x}{v}(1-v)$$

And then since $x>0$

We have

$$\frac{y}{x} = \frac{1-v}{v} = \frac{1}{v} - 1$$

Since $x>0 , y>0$, we know $\frac{y}{x}>0$, so we get

$$\frac{y}{x}= \frac{1}{v} - 1 > 0$$

And this means

$$\frac{1}{v} > 1$$

By examing the graph of $f(v) = \frac{1}{v}$, we get $0<v<1$.

Hope this can help you!

Comment: What about, can we easily say, x>0 and y>0 and from u=x+y, 0<u<∞ namely u is also positive and +=+*v , +=+*(1-v). So v>0 and (1-v)>0 then 0<v<1 ?

Comment: I think when I see that comment "Hint: v
 and 1−v
 must have the same sign."

Answer (score 1):

Since

$$ 0 < x < \infty $$

$$ 0 < y < \infty $$

then x and y are none zero positive numbers, so:

$$ u \cdot v >0$$

$$ u \cdot (1 - v) >0$$

If $u>0$ then $(1-v) >0 \rightarrow v<1$.
if $u<0$ then $(1-v) <0 \rightarrow v>1$ but since $ u \cdot v >0$ there is a contradiction, so u can not be negative.

(Note: If $u=0$ then $ u \cdot v >0$ is not possible so we can discard that possibility.)

Conclusion so far: $u>0$ and $v<1$. Now we have to show $v>0$.

Since $u>0$ and $u \cdot v >0$ then v must be positive $(v>0)$.

Hence $0 < v < 1$.

**Alternatively** starting with the simultaneous equations:

$ u \cdot v >0$

$ u \cdot (1 - v) >0$

add the two equations to get:

$uv + u(1-v) > 0 \rightarrow u>0$

Now we know u is not zero.

(a) Taking $ u \cdot (1 - v) >0$ and dividing both sides by u gives $1-v>0 \rightarrow 1>v$.

(b) Taking $ u v >0$ and dividing both sides by u gives $v>0$.

Taking (a) and (b) together, $0 < v < 1$.

Comment: Isn't that same thing with x>0 and y>0 and from u=x+y, 0<u<∞ namely u is also positive and +=+*v , +=+*(1-v). So v>0 and (1-v)>0 then 0<v<1 ?

Comment: x+y is equal to u

Comment: x+y = u is indeed true, which immediately confirms u>0. There are several ways to come to the same conclusion.

Comment: Does it also confirm if u, x and y>0 then 0<v<1

Comment: @LexusLS  That information on its own is not sufficient. You would need u>0 and u (1 - v) >0 to conclude v<1, but you could not confirm v>0 with just that information.. If you had u>0 and uv>o then you could conclude only that v>0. You need both uv>0 and u(1-v)>0 to conclude 0<v<1. (You don't need to given u>0 because it can be deduced from those two equations.)

Comment: Thank you KDP, I like your answer...

Comment: @LexusLS I added a slightly different method that might be slightly more efficient and traditional. Hope you like it also.